# pivot_longer in R and specify column type of name column to be date

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm trying to analyze some coronavirus data to look at cases per day and such.  I found data on the CDC website and it's in a non-tidy format, with each date having its own column.  I am using pivot_longer to transpose the data.  The following works to read in the data, pivot it, and use mutate to change the column data type of date to be date.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
deaths = read_csv("https://usafactsstatic.blob.core.windows.net/public/data/covid-19/covid_deaths_usafacts.csv")

deaths2 = deaths %>%
  rename(county = `County Name`, state = State) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(countyFIPS, county, state, stateFIPS), names_to = "date", values_to = "deaths_cumulative") %>%
  mutate(date = mdy(date)) %>%
  select(state, county, date, deaths_cumulative)
```

However, I am trying to use the names_ptypes argument of pivot_longer to specify the data type in that step.  If I do the following, the date column does end up with a data type of date, but all values in the column are NA.  I am not sure what's going on.  Perhaps it needs a format, but Date doesn't allow one, as far as I can tell.  Is there a way to do this?

```
deaths2 = deaths %>%
  rename(county = `County Name`, state = State) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(countyFIPS, county, state, stateFIPS), names_to = "date", values_to = "deaths_cumulative", names_ptypes = list(date = Date())) %>%
  select(state, county, date, deaths_cumulative)
```

Comment: I couldn't find the function `Date`, is it from `readr` or `lubridate`

Comment: @akrun Honestly, I'm not sure.  The help and examples I found online said you could use types like integer() or numeric(), so I tried date() and that didn't work (it left the values as character), then I tried Date() and it changed the column to date format but led to NAs.  So, the solution may involve Date or something else, or maybe it's not possible.

Comment: The `Date` is one function I couldn't find.  May be it is related to your package  version.  I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
library(tidyverse)
deaths2 <- deaths %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  gather(Xdate, deaths, -countyFIPS, - County.Name, - State, - stateFIPS) %>% 
  mutate(DATE = lubridate::as_date(lubridate::mdy(str_sub(Xdate,2)))) %>% 
  select(- Xdate)
```

`mdy` reformats the date-string so that `as_date` can coerce it.

Comment: I appreciate taking the time to answer, but my question is specifically how to do it within pivot_longer without having to use mutate and mdy after-the-fact.  If it were an integer column, pivot_longer can do that.  But, I'm not sure if it can do it with date.